# Jquery Filedrop: Russian characters in filename

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

Plugin(https://github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop) good work in Chrome, but in Mozilla I get error in binary XHR sending:

```
InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character
```

Filename looks like

```
Каталог_2.xls
```

Is it possible to make it work without files renaming?

Comment: I guess you need send email to the creator(s) of that plugin.

Comment: @Andron, Thank you, but I'd like to understand yourself and how to solve this.

Comment: Hmmm. Found such example in web: [link](http://www.grgr.us/jquery_plugins/filedrop.html). Tried to drag and drop image file with russian name - worked well in FF 20... So I think the issue is not with this plugin. Please show more code.

Answer (score 2):

file name has to be urlencoded. add this function to filedrop's default options:

```
var default_opts = {
    ...
    rename: function(name){ return encodeURIComponent(name); },
    ...
}
```

"Каталог_2.xls" => "%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3_2.xls"